# How to avoid non-copyable characters in a C application, run by Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, visual-studio, printf

I am working with a C application, which is tested by a Java application, run in Eclipse.
The Java application runs the C application, using the standard way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmdline)
```

(the `cmdline` containing the C application's executable)

The C application most probably uses Visual Studio's `vsprintf()` function for writing something, but in some cases, a non-copyable character seems to be printed, as you can see:

```
put_log(LOG_INFO, "Waiting for writing thread\n");
```

(`put_log()` is most probably based on the mentioned `vsprintf()`)
ps -ef
This gets shown in Eclipse as:

```
INFO : aiting for writing thread
```

As you see, the "W" has disappeared, and in top of that, when I try to copy the mentioned line, I only see:

```
INFO :
```

I have the impression that the letter `W` has been replaced by a character, which is not copyable to the Windows clipboard. As this happens in the middle of quite a large output, this is very annoying.

Does anybody understand what is going on and how I can solve this?

As asked by Fluter, hereby an excerpt of the `put_log()` function:

```
void put_log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  static char str[16384];
  char* args;
  char* p = str;

  strcpy(str, "INFO: ");

  p = str + strlen(str);

  _crt_va_start(args, fmt);
  vsprintf(p, fmt, args);
  _crt_va_end(args);
  ...
}
```

(the first argument(`LOG_INFO`) is removed from this excerpt and replaced by the `"INFO: "` hardcoded string for simplification purposes)

For your information, hereby the location of the lowlevel functions:

- `_crt_va_start()` : c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdarg.h
- `_crt_va_end()`   : c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\stdarg.h
- `vsprintf()`      : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src\vsprintf.c

Thanks

Comment: please post put_log of the C program

Comment: Why do your examples say `INFO : ` but the code says `INFO: `. Is it a typo or is this part of the bug?

Comment: Hello @Lundin, it was a typo indeed.

Comment: Have you copied the string "Waiting for writing thread\n" from somewhere else or typed it in? The behavior could be because the character "W" is some Unicode not supported by your terminal. What is the `break;` doing inside `put_log()`? What is the format string `LOG_INFO` you are using  ?

Comment: @farfanhubble: the string "Waiting ..." is simple ASCII, there is no Unicode involved. The `LOG_INFO` is an internal parameter which is used to distinguish info, warning or error messages (I have only shown the info part of the `put_log()` function, for simplification purposes. The `break` command was a leftover from a `switch` statement, I have removed it from the post.

Comment: Weird, because `put_log` should prepare a correct string as only plain ASCII seems involved... But anything could happen if you have undefined behaviour in another part of your code. Could you build a [mcve] that demonstrate the problem? And did you control the log file with a vanilla text editor outside Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post how is the log actually get printed on the console, make sure you print it with right functions, for example `fprintf(stderr, str);`

Second, you are using a static buffer here, it is subject to in data race when the function is called concurrently, possibly by multiple threads. Obviously the buffer is overwritten for every log, it does not make sense to use static here, yet brings the problem of corrupted data.

```
void put_log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    char str[16384];
    char* args;
    char* p = str;
    va_list list;

    strcpy(str, "INFO: ");

    p = str + strlen(str);

    va_start(list, fmt);
    vsprintf(p, fmt, list);
    va_end(list);

    fprintf(stderr, str);
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, the function `vsprintf(p, fmt, va);` is used, which seems to be a Visual Studio print() function.

Comment: @Dominique No, `vsprintf` prints the formatted string into the buffer pointed at p, it does not print the buffer to a file. That's why I said about calling `fprintf`.

Comment: Indeed. I have added `fprintf` at the end (as in the source code)

Comment: So what does the program output now?

Comment: The program is behaving exactly as mentioned: in some cases the first character of the output is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `_crt_va_start` behaves like standard C `va_start`, then you need to declare a `va_list` somewhere, rather than using some uninitialized char pointer. Reason why it seems to work is probably because va lists have non-existent type safety (and therefore using them to begin with is bad practice).

Do something like this instead:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

void put_log(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  static char str[16384];
  va_list va;
  char* p = str;

  strcpy(str, "INFO: ");
  p = str + strlen(str);

  va_start(va, fmt);
  vsprintf(p, fmt, va);
  va_end(va);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, Lundin, in order to have a short source excerpt I have thrown away too much lines: the `va_list` was declared at the beginning of the function, so in fact, my source code looks exactly as the one you propose. Meanwhile I've seen that the first letter of the message gets replaced by the character with ASCII code 0 (zero).

Comment: @Dominique So instead of wasting everyone's time, why don't you post a copy/paste of the exact code?

Comment: I understand your issue, Lundin, but my company is very strict on this matter.